# Using Javascript - Onclickevent of the button, an exe file needs to be downloaded and stored directly in the temp folder of the system

Tags: javascript, temp

When I click on a button, an .exe file which is stored in the root directory should directly download in the temp folder of the system. And I need to do this using JavaScript. I tried using c# but my requirement is with JavaScript. Can you please help me as I am new to JavaScript.

```cs
public void AutoClose() {
  string filename = "AutoClosure.exe";
  if (filename != "") {
    string path = Server.MapPath(@ "~\AutoClose\AutoClosure.exe");
    System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);
    if (file.Exists) {
      Response.Clear();
      Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
      Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
      Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
      Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
      Response.End();
    } else {
      Response.Write("This file does not exist.");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mahi27, please show your code, so we can help. thanks

Comment: Hi Abed, this is the code which i am using to run the .exe file. And then calling in the onClick function of the button, which leads in downloading option. But i need this using JavaScript. Where after clicking on the button, the file directly downloads in the temp folder of the system.

Comment: Hi Mahi27, thanks for your code, but please don't write the code at the comment. please edit your description and then write the code at description. thanks

Comment: Hi Abed, code is been updated in description. Can you please help.